# need an assembly code generator

Tags: python, assembly

My friend told me that I should use assembly to get my code to run faster, but it's really hard to program in and I don't know where to begin.

Are there any programs that can generate assembly from an easier language like python??

Comment: The OP may have some blind spots regarding to code generation, but IMHO the question is valid and clearly shows some effort ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, they're called compilers.

http://objectmix.com/python/337053-translating-python-assembler-3.html

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is wrong.  Most programs don't get demonstrably faster when written in assembly.  What makes assembly code fast is that assembly code programmers generally worry a lot about speed and size, and so that's the focus of their efforts.  Most compilers can do a much better job of creating fast programs than an only-average programmer can in assembly.